# Quit loop if a key is pressed

Tags: bash, shell-script, sh

I want to exit the script if any key is pressed.

```
#!/bin/sh
while true; do
   df -h | head
   sleep 10
   clear
done
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `sleep 10;` with `read -t 10 -n 1 exitwhile;   if [ -n "$exitwhile" ]; then break; fi`

`read -t 10 -n 1 exitwhile` waits 10sec for input without confirmation with enter and puts input into variable exitwhile. if that variable is not empty the while-loop will break.

…has to be modified though, because it will only break on character keys

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use `watch` command:

```
watch -n10 'df -h | head'
```

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to stop the command.

The `watch` man page says:

> watch - execute a program periodically, showing output fullscreen

Comment: You can Ctrl+C the original script. The point is to use *any* key.

Answer (score 0):

This will exit on almost any key:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
   { clear; df -h | head; } </dev/null
   read -n 1 -t 10 && break
done; read -t 0.1 -n 1000000
```

Notes:

- The shebang calls `bash`, not `sh`, because of `read -n`.
- The redirection from `/dev/null` is to prevent commands other than `read` from exhausting the stdin (`clear` and `df` may not do this, but in general commands may). This way any input goes to `read` eventually.
- The final `read` is to discard excessive characters from stdin. Some keys generate more than one character (research "escape sequences"); it's also possible to hit multiple keys while `df` (or any other command you wish to use) is running. Without the final `read` these extra characters would litter your command line.

---

Alternative approach, with `watch`:

```
#!/bin/bash
watch -n 10 df -h &   # put to the background
read -n 1
kill $!               # kill the the job most recently placed into the background
read -t 0.1 -n 1000000
```